# Update and append to all items in a specific column

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, sql-update

How do I append a character to all items `purchase_id' here is a manual example of what I want...

```
SELECT * 
FROM `loadable_link` 
WHERE `product_sku` = '2101-R' 
ORDER BY `customer_id` DESC
```

Then select from purchased_id and append a '0' to all purchased ID's

```
UPDATE `loadable_link` SET `purchased_id` = '11165690' 
WHERE `loadable_link`.`purchased_id` = 1116569;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update the table according to the condition in the original `select` statement.

If `purchase_id` is a number, you can multiply it by 10:

```sql
UPDATE `loadable_link`
SET    `purchase_id` = `purchase_id` * 10
WHERE  `product_sku` = '2101-R'
```

If `purchase_id` is a string, you can concatenate a `0` to it:

```sql
UPDATE `loadable_link`
SET    `purchase_id` = CONCAT(`purchase_id`, '0')
WHERE  `product_sku` = '2101-R'
```

Answer (score 1):

```sql
UPDATE `loadable_link`
SET `purchased_id` = CONCAT(`purchased_id`, "0")
WHERE `product_sku` = "2101-R";
```

This can be achieved in one `UPDATE` query, take the original value of each row and `CONCAT()` to append a `0` to the end of the existing `purchase_id`.